# What should be the datatype for purchase column in a database table?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-redshift, ddl

What should be the data type for the `purchase` column in a database table?

I have a column called `purchase` which is the purchase amount for a product.

Should it be `DECIMAL`, `REAL` or `FLOAT`?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

Answer (score 1):

For money columns, I'd always prefer type `decimal` (`numeric`). Types `double`, `real` or `float` have the rounding problems, so `$0.42` could be internally stored as `$0.41999999999` or `$0.42000000001`. In money business this could end in unexpected behaviour and wrong results.

This can be avoided by using the `decimal` type which guarantees to store the exact value.